# Restrictions on a set of values: defining a type usable by many elements (XML Schema)

Tags: xml, xsd, restriction

I found [here](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/schema_facets.asp) the following example about restrictions on a set of values, but I didn't get how to use the type carType in other elements.

```
<xs:element name="car" type="carType"/>

<xs:simpleType name="carType">
  <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
    <xs:enumeration value="Audi"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="Golf"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="BMW"/>
  </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

Maybe in this way? Have I to rewrite all the rows about carType?

```
<xs:element name="car2" type="carType"/>

<xs:simpleType name="carType">
  <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
    <xs:enumeration value="Audi"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="Golf"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="BMW"/>
  </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define type just once:

```
<xs:simpleType name="carType">
  <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
    <xs:enumeration value="Audi"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="Golf"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="BMW"/>
  </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

and re-use it for as many elements as you need:

```
<xs:element name="car" type="carType"/>
<xs:element name="car2" type="carType"/>
```